# Value Object Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good morning, first sorry my English because I'm using Google Translate.

I'm starting now with Python and Django and me a question arose in the creation of my models. I would like to create something like:

Person (models.Model)

- Name
- ...
- Address

Address(models.Model)

- PublicPlace
- Neighborhood
- ...

That is, the address as a separate ValueObject in order to use more than one model. In the database fields within the address class will be persisted within the People table and other entities that may arise (Enterprise, Client, "Anyone who may have address"). So avoid duplicating all address fields for each model you need.

I saw that would to do by setting the Meta class address for abstract and inheriting the others. But if I want to do more ValueObjects, have to inherit from several classes for this, I wonder if there is a more correct way.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to persist the fields within Person etc, rather than having Address as a concrete model and using a relationship?

Comment: It would be a 1..1 relationship in this particular case was planning to leave the same table. These classes are used only as an example, could be another ValueObject. I usually work with .NET and DDD, and wanted to know how to apply this in Django ...

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    address = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
```

In this many, one person could have multiple addresses, and each address could have multiple people. If you want to allow only one address per person, use

```
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

This still allows multiple people per address.

Comment: I would like to address class function as a data structure only, not as an entity. If it were an entity, for this example, would be a 1..1 relationship. I would like to know how to write ValueObjects (concept of "DDD" architecture). Another example would be if I determine one Contact class, which always have the fields "Telephone", "Mobile" and "Email", so would Pessoa.Contato.Telefone. Without necessarily record in another table.